# how I add category dropdwon with custom option in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, catalog

> how I  add category dropdwon with custom option in magento 2

Comment: Can You Provide Some More details @Rahul Katoch

Comment: I need to crate custom category attribute with drop down options can you please let me know how I create drop down category option ?

Comment: Where you need to add that ?